# Activation pending in CQ5

Tags: aem

I have created a test page in the Geometrixx site in CQ5. I can see the page very well on 4502 port (author environment). But when I activate the page to see it on the 4503 port (Publish environment) , I always see the yellow colored icon in front of the page on console which on hover says 'Activation pending. #1 in Queue'

Is there some workflow attached to it ? If so, how can I check it out and probably kill it (for now) ? Or is there some other reason ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default replication queue settings points to localhost:4503. If your publish instance is not located on the same machine as the author instance (which is common), you will need to change the settings to point to a valid publish instance. Once a valid publish instance is configured the items queued for activation should get processed and the icons will change from yellow to green.

If the queue is blocked, you can clear it by:

- going to /etc/replication/agents.author.html
- Clicking on the default replication agent.
- Then clicking on 'clear' above the queue. This will clear the entire
  queue.
- If you want to clear one or more specific items in the queue, you can select
  them then click clear.

This page has a few steps on troubleshooting replication agents:
http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/replication-stuck.html

This page has some general information about replication agents:
[http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_cq.html#Replicating from Author to Publish](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_cq.html#Replicating%20from%20Author%20to%20Publish)

Comment: both links are 404 now

Answer (score 5):

You can inspect the replication queues at

```
http://localhost:4502/etc/replication.html
```

The default agent is

```
http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/agents.author/publish.html
```

From here you can test the connection, view the log, and see what's in the queue. You can also clear the queue or force retry.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to see a "final View" of your test page without to publish: `wcmmode=disabled`

```
http:// localhost: 4502/cf#/content/geometrixx/folder/test.html
```

Just delete /cf# and add `?wcmmode=disabled` after the extension.

```
http:// localhost: 4502/content/geometrixx/folder/test.html?wcmmode=disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing not explicitly mentioned so far: You need TWO instances of AEM running.  Ports 4502 and 4503 don't point to different modes of the same instance, as AEM only listens to the one port (in general).  So you will need to copy your Author jar to a new directory and name it something like cq5-publish-4503.jar

In addition, you may need to update your maven pom files for code deploys.  You CAN set installed bundles on author to auto replicate/publish however.